# should I use semi-colon or just a comma?

Tags: semicolons

I'm writing an essay and feels that this sentence is somehow punctuated wrong

What is the proper way to punctuate this sentence?

> Financing arts is not a horrible idea, but when the public services like health and education isn’t getting the suitable funding; it seems like one.

Answer (score 2):

You use a semicolon to join two complete sentences that are in some way closely related.  Now "It seems like one" is a complete sentence. but

> Financing arts is not a horrible idea, but when the public services like health and education isn’t getting the suitable funding

is not a complete sentence. So a semicolon or a full stop can't be used.